# Put image out of container - bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I need to place an image outside the container, so that the right margin stays the default container (responsive), and the image always stays together with a button.

Follow the image below to exemplify:

[image]

I tried to use container-fluid (Example 2 - using container-fluid in html), but I can't use the same margin as the container on the right side. I can change by css, but would have to change for all breakpoints, has another way?

I tried to use the container itself (Example 3 - using container and margin-left: 0px in html) and remove the margin-left without success.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <title>Examples</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

</head>

<body>
    <h2>Example 1</h2>
    <div class="">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-6 row">
                    <div class="col pl-0 mt-5">
                        <div class="nav nav-pills"  aria-orientation="vertical">
                            <a class="nav-link active" >Example1</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                    <h1>Test</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus sit ipsum ullam, necessitatibus quia laboriosam provident, culpa molestias cum magnam error fugiat voluptatem blanditiis dignissimos modi. Reprehenderit repudiandae nisi dolor?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ex1 mt-5">
        <h3>Example 2 - using container-fluid</h3>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-6 row">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
                    <div class="col pl-0 mt-5">
                        <div class="nav nav-pills"  aria-orientation="vertical">
                            <a class="nav-link active" >Example1</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                    <h1>Test</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus sit ipsum ullam, necessitatibus quia laboriosam provident, culpa molestias cum magnam error fugiat voluptatem blanditiis dignissimos modi. Reprehenderit repudiandae nisi dolor?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mt-5">
        <h3>Example 3 - using container and margin-left: 0px</h3>
        <div class="container" style="margin-left: 0px">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-6 row">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
                    <div class="col pl-0 mt-5">
                        <div class="nav nav-pills"  aria-orientation="vertical">
                            <a class="nav-link active" >Example1</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                    <h1>Test</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus sit ipsum ullam, necessitatibus quia laboriosam provident, culpa molestias cum magnam error fugiat voluptatem blanditiis dignissimos modi. Reprehenderit repudiandae nisi dolor?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Would anyone know any way to do it without me having to change this margin-right on all breakpoints?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in bootstrap.

If you give your button position:relative then it will no longer flow with the rest of the grid and can always be to the right of the image/text

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

is a good tutorial on different position options

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always make use of
 display: flex; 
which would allow do what you have above easily.

Checkout how to use flex